# Android local VPN Service: can't get response

Tags: java, android, vpn, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm quite new to Android and its services. I'm trying to implement a **local** VPN service in my app (with Kotlin and Java).

### QUESTION

My VPN service taken from [ToyVpn](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/ToyVpnClient.java) Google example, combined with examples from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766405/android-vpnservice-to-capture-packets-wont-capture-packets), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237743/android-firewall-with-vpnservice), [3](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/android-vpn-service/) to use it locally (without connection to remote server) is NOT working.

---

### MY APP PRINCIPE

*I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766405/android-vpnservice-to-capture-packets-wont-capture-packets) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237743/android-firewall-with-vpnservice) SO questions, but the answers there aren't very insightful and I can't find the solution for my issue.*

**So the app is pretty simple**: it should forward all of the packets when user click "YES"-button on the main activity, and when click "NO" - block it. The purpose: *to use it as a **firewall***, like that:

[image: The principle of my VPN app]

All of my code is written on Kotlin language, but it's not complicated and is very clear for JAVA developers. So I hope the code above is pretty clear as it is taken from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/ToyVpnClient.java) (ToyVpn example provided by Google) and just converted to kotlin.

---

### MY CONFIGURATION & CODE

To enable VPN service in my app I placed in my **AndroidManifest.xml** into `<application>` tag this setting:

```
<service android:name="com.example.username.wifictrl.model.VpnFilter"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.VpnService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

My **MainActivity** code contains:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ... // omitted for the sake of brevity

        val intent = VpnService.prepare(this);
        if (intent != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } else {
            onActivityResult(0, RESULT_OK, null);
        }

        ... // omitted for the sake of brevity
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val intent = Intent(this, VpnFilter::class.java);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }
```

My **VpnFilter class** is quite similar to [ToyVpn](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/ToyVpnService.java) service class, but has to work locally without any authentication, handshake etc, so I've edited example with such settings:

```
 private void configure() throws Exception {
    // If the old interface has exactly the same parameters, use it!
    if (mInterface != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Using the previous interface");
        return;
    }

    // Configure a builder while parsing the parameters.
    Builder builder = new Builder();
    builder.setSession(TAG)
    builder.addAddress("10.0.0.2", 32).addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
    try {
        mInterface.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    mInterface = builder.establish();
}
```

And in my **run** function I've just configured tunnel to connect to the local IP address:

```
tunnel.connect(InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8087))
```

Thereby:

1. the **settings** of the VPN configurations are quite similar to [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/android-vpn-service/) example and both examples from SO questions, mentioned above, for local usage.
2. and my **packet forwarding** is taken from [ToyVpn](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/ToyVpnService.java) example.

I know that my VPN is running, because if I change **addRoute** configuration, I won't be able to access Internet.

So I don't know what I'm actually doing wrong! If I use code for packet forwarding from ToyVpn, app is **crashing** every time **new packet comes**.

**Update**

The above is solved, but I see, that packets are sending away, but I cannot get any response. I can't figure out why.

---

### FULL JAVA CODE OF MY VPN SERVICE

```
public class VpnFilter extends VpnService implements Handler.Callback, Runnable {
    private static final String TAG = "MyVpnService";

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Thread mThread;

    private ParcelFileDescriptor mInterface;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // The handler is only used to show messages.
        if (mHandler == null) {
            mHandler = new Handler(this);
        }

        // Stop the previous session by interrupting the thread.
        if (mThread != null) {
            mThread.interrupt();
        }

        // Start a new session by creating a new thread.
        mThread = new Thread(this, "ToyVpnThread");
        mThread.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mThread != null) {
            mThread.interrupt();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
        if (message != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, message.what, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        Log.i(TAG,"running vpnService");
        try {
            runVpnConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Log.e(TAG, "Got " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                mInterface.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }
            mInterface = null;

            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(R.string.disconnected);
            Log.i(TAG, "Exiting");
        }
    }

    private void configure() throws Exception {
        // If the old interface has exactly the same parameters, use it!
        if (mInterface != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Using the previous interface");
            return;
        }

        // Configure a builder while parsing the parameters.
        Builder builder = new Builder();
        builder.setSession(TAG)
        builder.addAddress("10.0.0.2", 32).addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
        try {
            mInterface.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }

        mInterface = builder.establish();
    }

    private boolean runVpnConnection() throws Exception {

        configure()

        val in = new FileInputStream(mInterface.fileDescriptor)

        // Packets received need to be written to this output stream.
        val out = new FileOutputStream(mInterface.fileDescriptor)

        // The UDP channel can be used to pass/get ip package to/from server
        val tunnel = DatagramChannel.open()

        // For simplicity, we use the same thread for both reading and
        // writing. Here we put the tunnel into non-blocking mode.
        tunnel.configureBlocking(false)

        // Allocate the buffer for a single packet.
        val packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(32767)

        // Connect to the server, localhost is used for demonstration only.
        tunnel.connect(InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8087))

        // Protect this socket, so package send by it will not be feedback to the vpn service.
        protect(tunnel.socket())

        // We use a timer to determine the status of the tunnel. It
        // works on both sides. A positive value means sending, and
        // any other means receiving. We start with receiving.
        int timer = 0

        // We keep forwarding packets till something goes wrong.
        while (true) {
            // Assume that we did not make any progress in this iteration.
            boolean idle = true

            // Read the outgoing packet from the input stream.
            int length = `in`.read(packet.array())

            if (length > 0) {

                Log.i(TAG, "************new packet")

                // Write the outgoing packet to the tunnel.
                packet.limit(length)
                tunnel.write(packet);
                packet.clear()
                // There might be more outgoing packets.
                idle = false
                // If we were receiving, switch to sending.
                if (timer < 1) {
                    timer = 1
                }

            }

            length = tunnel.read(packet)

            if (length > 0) {
                // Ignore control messages, which start with zero.
                if (packet.get(0).toInt() !== 0) {
                    // Write the incoming packet to the output stream.
                    out.write(packet.array(), 0, length)
                }
                packet.clear()
                // There might be more incoming packets.
                idle = false
                // If we were sending, switch to receiving.
                if (timer > 0) {
                    timer = 0
                }
            }
            // If we are idle or waiting for the network, sleep for a
            // fraction of time to avoid busy looping.
            if (idle) {
                Thread.sleep(100)
                // Increase the timer. This is inaccurate but good enough,
                // since everything is operated in non-blocking mode.
                timer += if (timer > 0) 100 else -100
                // We are receiving for a long time but not sending.
                if (timer < -15000) {
                    // Send empty control messages.
                    packet.put(0.toByte()).limit(1)
                    for (i in 0..2) {
                        packet.position(0)
                        tunnel.write(packet)
                    }
                    packet.clear()
                    // Switch to sending.
                    timer = 1
                }
                // We are sending for a long time but not receiving.
                if (timer > 20000) {
                    throw IllegalStateException("Timed out")
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(50)
        }
    }
}
```

---

### LOG CAT OUTPUT

In my **LogCat** panel I've got this trace when app crashes:

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.username.wifictrl.model.VpnFilter@41ebbfb8 with null: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter intent
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2950)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:151)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter intent
              at com.example.skogs.wifictrl.model.VpnFilter.onStartCommand(VpnFilter.kt)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2916)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442) 
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520) 
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796) 
              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Learn how to create a [MCVE].

Comment: @nhaarman thank's for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error logged in logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter intent
              at com.example.skogs.wifictrl.model.VpnFilter.onStartCommand(VpnFilter.kt)
```

indicates the problem.

The documentation of [`onStartCommand`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) states that (emphasis mine):

> Intent: The Intent supplied to startService(Intent), as given. **This
>   may be null** if the service is being restarted after its process has
>   gone away, and it had previously returned anything except
>   START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY.

Hence  you should handle the `null` case accordingly at the very least by changing the signature of `onStartCommand` in Kotlin to:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent:Intent?, flags:Int, startId:Int) {
```

Comment: I've updated the question. I've faced another problem. I can't get any response, but I see that bytes are sending away. 
My interface has such configureation: builder.addAddress("10.0.0.2", 32).addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
And my tunnel is connected to tunnel.connect(InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 55555)).
I suppose, I don't understand something.. But as I can see other examples, their packet forwarding is working with such configurations. Can you give a tip, what might be wrong?
Thank you very much!

Comment: @heyjohnnyfunt The updated question seems like a problem with different root cause - the one I answered was about language usage - whereas the problem you're having now seems related to Android API usage and network configuration. I guess it would make sense to create a separate question with an image of network nodes (with addresses) and description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I think most of us overlook the [ToyVpnServer.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/server/linux) which is needed to complete the solution. Anyway, I am not sure how to implement that piece on Android with no root access.