# Android local VPN Service: can not forward packets

Tags: java, android, networking, ip, kotlin

I'm trying to implement simple Android firewall app through VPN service.

Basic scheme looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to simply forward packets through my VPN service. So I've started with implementing [ToyVpn](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn) Google example (time to time taking a glance at [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/android-vpn-service/) example) for my purposes, but it's not working: when my VPN is running I see that packets are sent, but I've got no response.

*App is written on Kotlin, but it's not complicated for Java lovers.*

My **Builder** is configured with IP and route as shown below:

```
val builder = Builder()
builder.addAddress("10.0.0.2", 32).addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
mInterface = builder.establish()
```

After that I'm setting a **tunnel** a way it's shown in ToyVpn, but my VPN server destination IP address is local:

```
val tunnel = DatagramChannel.open()
if (!protect(tunnel.socket())) {
    throw IllegalStateException("Cannot protect the tunnel");
}
tunnel.connect(InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 55555))
tunnel.configureBlocking(false)
protect(tunnel.socket())
```

After that I'm trying to forward packets from `in` and `out` FileInputStream's (also taken from ToyVpn):

```
val `in` = FileInputStream(mInterface!!.fileDescriptor)
val out = FileOutputStream(mInterface!!.fileDescriptor)
var timer = 0
        while (true) {
            var idle = true

            var length = `in`.read(packet.array())

            if (length > 0) {
                packet.limit(length)
                tunnel.write(packet);
                packet.clear()
                idle = false
                if (timer < 1) {
                    timer = 1
                }

            }
            length = tunnel.read(packet)

            if (length > 0) {
                if (packet.get(0).toInt() !== 0) {
                    out.write(packet.array(), 0, length)
                }
                packet.clear()
                idle = false
                if (timer > 0) {
                    timer = 0
                }
            }
            if (idle) {
                Thread.sleep(100)
                timer += if (timer > 0) 100 else -100
                if (timer < -15000) {
                    packet.put(0.toByte()).limit(1)
                    for (i in 0..2) {
                        packet.position(0)
                        tunnel.write(packet)
                    }
                    packet.clear()
                    timer = 1
                }
                if (timer > 20000) {
                    throw IllegalStateException("Timed out")
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(50)
        }
```

**My first question:** What am I doing wrong? The code is clear and should work properly, but it does not!

Basicly I want my service to fitler packets by IP address. I know that huge apps like [tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture&hl=ru) parse packets from the scratch and than reconstruct them.

**My second question:** Is there a way to make packet filtering simplier if I want to fetch only the IP address?

**P.S.:** Actualy I've already asked a similar question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779720/android-local-vpn-service-cant-get-response) a few days ago, but error had another nature related to Kotlin language, which app is developed on. Also I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766405/android-vpnservice-to-capture-packets-wont-capture-packets) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237743/android-firewall-with-vpnservice) questions, but the answers there didn't help me.

Comment: It was a long time, but did you solve this problem?