# How to capture packets from applications protected from sniffing

Tags: java, android, networking, android-vpn-service

I'm working on sniffing packets from Facebook android application. I want to use the sniffed data in my study of users behavior on social networks.

What I learned in the last two months is that I have to create a vpn service and use it to sniff data. There are a lot of useful codes on the internet that I tried to understand and run. And I managed to sniff the data of some applications using these codes, which all uses the same concept.

- https://github.com/hexene/LocalVPN
- [Android firewall with VpnService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237743/)
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/Android-vpn-service/
- [Android VpnService to capture packets won't capture packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766405)

When using each one of the above code, and with small modifications, I managed to capture packets for all applications, but with applications like facebook, the vpnService made those applications stop working; when I create the vpn service and I try for example to comment on a post or make any action that requires sending/receiving data between Facebook application and Facebook server, this action doesn't happen; looks like somehow Facebook application knows that there's someone sniffing on him.

I've been trying in the last two months to find a way to capture Facebook application packets without breaking the Facebook application functionality.

I tried to install a certificate following the [KeyChain demo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/KeyChainDemo) in android samples, but it didn't work with me.

From my search, I know/I'm sure that there's something I'm missing; I searched for applications that does what I'm trying to accomplish without making applications like facebook detect it. And I found [LostNetNoRootFirewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lostnet.fw.free) on google play.

With [LostNetNoRootFirewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lostnet.fw.free), I managed to create a vpn service and sniff packets, and facebook application was working like a charm!

### My question

What should I add to my application to be able to create a vpnService and prevent applications like facebook from detecting that my service is sniffing it's packets?

## The current code I'm working at. [original source from [here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237743/android-firewall-with-vpnservice)

```
package com.git.firewall;

public class GITVpnService extends VpnService implements Handler.Callback, Runnable {
    private static final String TAG = "GITVpnService";

    private String mServerAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    private int mServerPort = 55555;
    private PendingIntent mConfigureIntent;

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Thread mThread;

    private ParcelFileDescriptor mInterface;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // The handler is only used to show messages.
        if (mHandler == null) {
            mHandler = new Handler(this);
        }

        // Stop the previous session by interrupting the thread.
        if (mThread != null) {
            mThread.interrupt();
        }
        // Start a new session by creating a new thread.
        mThread = new Thread(this, "VpnThread");
        mThread.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mThread != null) {
            mThread.interrupt();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
        if (message != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, (String)message.obj, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting");
            InetSocketAddress server = new InetSocketAddress(
                    mServerAddress, mServerPort);

            run(server);

              } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Got " + e.toString());
            try {
                mInterface.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                // ignore
            }
            Message msgObj = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            msgObj.obj = "Disconnected";
            mHandler.sendMessage(msgObj);

        } finally {

        }
    }

    DatagramChannel mTunnel = null;


    private boolean run(InetSocketAddress server) throws Exception {
        boolean connected = false;

        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

        // Create a DatagramChannel as the VPN tunnel.
        mTunnel = DatagramChannel.open();

        // Protect the tunnel before connecting to avoid loopback.
        if (!protect(mTunnel.socket())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot protect the tunnel");
        }

        // Connect to the server.
        mTunnel.connect(server);

        // For simplicity, we use the same thread for both reading and
        // writing. Here we put the tunnel into non-blocking mode.
        mTunnel.configureBlocking(false);

        // Authenticate and configure the virtual network interface.
        handshake();

        // Now we are connected. Set the flag and show the message.
        connected = true;
        Message msgObj = mHandler.obtainMessage();
        msgObj.obj = "Connected";
        mHandler.sendMessage(msgObj);

        new Thread ()
        {
            public void run ()
                {
                    // Packets to be sent are queued in this input stream.
                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
                    // Allocate the buffer for a single packet.
                    ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(32767);
                    int length;
                    try
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            while ((length = in.read(packet.array())) > 0) {
                                    // Write the outgoing packet to the tunnel.
                                    packet.limit(length);
                                    debugPacket(packet);    // Packet size, Protocol, source, destination
                                    mTunnel.write(packet);
                                    packet.clear();

                                }
                            }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        }.start();

        new Thread ()
        {

            public void run ()
            {
                    DatagramChannel tunnel = mTunnel;
                    // Allocate the buffer for a single packet.
                    ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(8096);
                    // Packets received need to be written to this output stream.
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());

                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // Read the incoming packet from the tunnel.
                            int length;
                            while ((length = tunnel.read(packet)) > 0)
                            {
                                    // Write the incoming packet to the output stream.
                                out.write(packet.array(), 0, length);

                                packet.clear();

                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException ioe)
                        {
                                ioe.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            }
        }.start();

        return connected;
    }

    private void handshake() throws Exception {

        if (mInterface == null)
        {
            Builder builder = new Builder();

            builder.setMtu(1500);
            builder.addAddress("10.0.0.2",32);
            builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0);
            //builder.addRoute("192.168.2.0",24);
            //builder.addDnsServer("8.8.8.8");

            // Close the old interface since the parameters have been changed.
            try {
                mInterface.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }


            // Create a new interface using the builder and save the parameters.
            mInterface = builder.setSession("GIT VPN")
                    .setConfigureIntent(mConfigureIntent)
                    .establish();
        }
    }

    private void debugPacket(ByteBuffer packet)
    {
        /*
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            byte buffer = packet.get();

            Log.d(TAG, "byte:"+buffer);
        }*/



        int buffer = packet.get();
        int version;
        int headerlength;
        version = buffer >> 4;
        headerlength = buffer & 0x0F;
        headerlength *= 4;
        Log.d(TAG, "IP Version:"+version);
        Log.d(TAG, "Header Length:"+headerlength);

        String status = "";
        status += "Header Length:"+headerlength;

        buffer = packet.get();      //DSCP + EN
        buffer = packet.getChar();  //Total Length

        Log.d(TAG, "Total Length:"+buffer);

        buffer = packet.getChar();  //Identification
        buffer = packet.getChar();  //Flags + Fragment Offset
        buffer = packet.get();      //Time to Live
        buffer = packet.get();      //Protocol

        Log.d(TAG, "Protocol:"+buffer);

        status += "  Protocol:"+buffer;

        buffer = packet.getChar();  //Header checksum

        String sourceIP  = "";
        buffer = packet.get();  //Source IP 1st Octet
        sourceIP += buffer;
        sourceIP += ".";

        buffer = packet.get();  //Source IP 2nd Octet
        sourceIP += buffer;
        sourceIP += ".";

        buffer = packet.get();  //Source IP 3rd Octet
        sourceIP += buffer;
        sourceIP += ".";

        buffer = packet.get();  //Source IP 4th Octet
        sourceIP += buffer;

        Log.d(TAG, "Source IP:"+sourceIP);

        status += "   Source IP:"+sourceIP;

        String destIP  = "";
        buffer = packet.get();  //Destination IP 1st Octet
        destIP += buffer;
        destIP += ".";

        buffer = packet.get();  //Destination IP 2nd Octet
        destIP += buffer;
        destIP += ".";

        buffer = packet.get();  //Destination IP 3rd Octet
        destIP += buffer;
        destIP += ".";

        buffer = packet.get();  //Destination IP 4th Octet
        destIP += buffer;

        Log.d(TAG, "Destination IP:"+destIP);

        status += "   Destination IP:"+destIP;
        /*
        msgObj = mHandler.obtainMessage();
        msgObj.obj = status;
        mHandler.sendMessage(msgObj);
        */

        //Log.d(TAG, "version:"+packet.getInt());
        //Log.d(TAG, "version:"+packet.getInt());
        //Log.d(TAG, "version:"+packet.getInt());

    }

}
```

Comment: One way Facebook can detect accounts using V.P.N. is because it keep a list of IP address ranges that are know for V.P.N. usage .A second way is when you sign into your account using V.P.N., your IP address suddenly may not fall into the range Facebook has associated with your location. So choose a plausible I.P. address if you can. Remember Facebook regularly blocks accounts when it see's suspicious activity (and it looks VERY hard at your activity).

Comment: Q: why do you use a vpn and not wireshark or even tcpdump?

Comment: I would ask the developers of https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evbadroid.proxymon&hl=en or any similar app on how they did it