# Is TCP packet filtering possible on mobile platforms?

Tags: android, ios, networking, tcp, port

I'm interested on having my mobile app run in the background and filter TCP packets.

I know I'll face restrictions due to sandboxing, each OS privilege levels and how iOS handles background tasks so I want to confirm if it's possible to do it on iOS and Android.

Do Android and iOS allow you to analyze and modify packets going through TCP ports? If it's possible how? Could I do it while my app remains on the background?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### iOS

I don't think it is possible on iOS.

I didn't find a public API for network monitoring/packet filtering. There is a possibility that such API exists but it's hidden. But in that case [Apple App Store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality) states:

> 2.5 Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

If you need one specific quote to show that it is not possible, you can use this:

> iOS does not support packet tracing directly. However, if you connect your iOS device to a Mac via USB...

from [official Apple Technical Q&A QA1176](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1176/_index.html).

#### Alternatives

The next best thing is to a configure a proxy server manually in Settings and then filter the traffic on the server-side. Running the proxy locally, on the device is not an option because of [limitations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) of iOS background tasks:

> 2.16 Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.

Also, [this](http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/) post suggests it might be possible to set-up a VPN connection programmatically on iOS 8. It would also require to send the traffic of the device and I'm not sure about compliance of this method with guidelines.

#### Non-alternatives

Some apps provide functionality of measuring the network traffic. But they use dedicated API for network statistics: [iPhone Data Usage Tracking/Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring).

There are also ways to packet trace on iOS via USB cable described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1176/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001707-CH1-SECIOSPACKETTRACING).

### Android

On Android you can configure the device to use your app as a [VPN service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html). But:

- It requires you to display a dialog describing the consequences of giving a permission to act as a VPN.
- You have to show a persistent notification while VPN is active. An example of app that does it is [tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture).

To ask for user permission, you call `VpnService.prepare`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(getApplicationContext());
     if (intent != null) {
          startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
     } else {
          onActivityResult(0, RESULT_OK, null);
     }
}
```

and handle the result, starting your VpnService.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyVpnService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Your `VpnService` have to implement `public int onStartCommand()`. The service is treated as a foreground service and should not get killed by the OS.

This question: [Android VpnService to capture packets won't capture packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766405/android-vpnservice-to-capture-packets-wont-capture-packets) and it's comments shed some light on the packet handling itself.

Comment: I concur, this is not possible on iOS.

Comment: Is there any way to confirm it's not possible on iOS, maybe the official documentation or app store rules? This is related to a client's request so I want to be able to show him something maybe from official sources.

Comment: I updated the answer with anything I managed to find on the topic. Good luck :)

Comment: hi @atok I've been investigating into using VpnService on Android. However to my understanding while it's possible to read packets this way, it's not possible to modify them and resend them on a transparent way without basically having to reimplement the TCP protocol. Do you know if this is true? Some apps doing this are "Mobilwol: No root firewall" and "NoRoot Firewall" by GreyShirts.

Comment: my doubt basically is whether with VpnService I can modify the packets and forward them so they keep their normal route

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is for Android only**

Generally **YES** it is possible!
There are some problems though.

Here is a List what works and what problems you will encounter.

**Filtering via VPN Service**

- Very High impact on Battery
- Proxy support won't work
- Allows modifiying of traffic

**Filtering via libpcap**

- Requires root
- Does not allow to modify traffic

**Filtering with IPTables/PFTables/libnetfilter**

- Requires root
- Needs a kernel module
- Won't work on any devices where you have not the kernel source or it is not integrated

**Filtering using Xposed Framework**

- Requires root
- Will only work with Dalvik Systems
- Won't work with Applications build with NDK

**Filtering with Cydia Substrate**

- Requires root
- Will only work with Dalvik Systems
- Currently in Beta state

So Yes it is possible, but at what costs?
If you need it just for yourself, you are good by using `Cydia Substrate` as it supports 100% of Applications but it requires a dalvik system.

If you want to publish it to the Store you should use the VPN Service. It might be possible to create the service using the NDK, then you might have lowered the battery problems.

I hope I have helped you in some way.

Comment: hi @Eun I've been investigating into using VpnService to implement it on Android. I know now it's possible without rooting as some apps like "Mobilwol: No root firewall" and "NoRoot Firewall" by GreyShirts are doing it. However I've been told that while it's possible to read packets this way, it's not possible to modify them and resend them on a transparent way without basically having to reimplement the TCP protocol. Do you know if this is true?

Answer (score 1):

You can build apps using the Android VPN service that can do interesting things like filter packets, among other things. You can find a VPN example in "Android Samples for SDK", which can be found in the [Google Source Code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/).

Cliff Robinson
Community Manager
[BackBox](http://backbox.co)

Answer (score 0):

On iOS I would say that it depends on whether or not you allow the device being jailbroken as an acceptable precondition. There are some references to [PF](http://jhellenthal.wordpress.com/2014/01/12/packet-filtering-on-the-iphone-theres-an-app-for-that/) as well as a [network sniffer](https://code.google.com/p/n1mda-dev/wiki/PirniUsageGuide) (Which I assume must work in a similar way) for iOS.

PF is [open source](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.22.73/bsd/net/pf.c) but unfortunately built in C.

Comment: so it's not possible without jailbreaking the phone? Is there any way to confirm this, maybe the official documentation or app store rules?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Like @atok says, a good alternative is probably to set up an external proxy or VPN which will filter the traffic for you.