# How to specify a global HTTP proxy with WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I've been starting to experiment with WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager for both IOS and Android devices.  For IOS devices, some MDM packages offer the ability to set a global HTTP proxy.  Is this possible with WSO2 EMM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible on "supervised" devices.  This can only be activated by using Apple Configurator at time of setup.

Comment: Liked your question. Hey what's about Android? How can set up a proxy on Android via WSO2 EMM?

Comment: No, Android does not currently support global proxys set like that.  I think it can be done with root but that didn't fit our usage scenario.  For Samsung devices it can be done with SEAP but not through WSO2 EMM.

Comment: AFAIK Android does support global proxy via  `VpnService` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766405/android-vpnservice-to-capture-packets-wont-capture-packets

Comment: Android also supports a global proxy using device owner mode.