# Android VpnService forward packets

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, packet-capture

I want to use android's `VpnService` to capture packets filter them based off IP address. I can get the packets from the "tun" interface just fine but after that i'm not sure how to forward them to their original destination. Based off of the comments from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17820461/4893507) it seems like i just need to:

1. Create a new socket to the destination IP address and port
2. Trim the IP and TCP header to send only the data
3. Re-attach the IP and TCP header when i get a response
4. Send the complete packet to the output stream

I have tried to send the data like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(0));
if (protect(socket)){
    Log.e(TAG, "Socket protected");
}else{
    Log.e(TAG, "Socket NOT protected");
}
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipPacket.getDestinationIp(), ipPacket.getDstPort()));
Log.e(TAG, "Socket connected: " + socket.isConnected());

socket.getOutputStream().write(getTCPHeader(getIpHeader(packet)[1])[1].array());
```

The methods `getTCPHeader(ByteArray packet)` and `getIpHeader(ByteArray packet)` simply splits the packet into two `ByteArray`'s as follows:

```
private ByteBuffer[] getIpHeader(ByteBuffer packet){
    packet.position(0);
    ByteBuffer ipHeader = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
    ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocate(packet.limit() - 20);
    
    packet.get(ipHeader.array(), 0, 20);
    
    packet.get(data.array(), 0, packet.limit() - 20);
    
    return new ByteBuffer[]{ipHeader, data};
}

private ByteBuffer[] getTCPHeader(ByteBuffer packet){
    packet.position(20);
    ByteBuffer tcpHeader = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
    ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocate(packet.limit() - 20);

    packet.get(tcpHeader.array(), 0, 20);

    packet.get(data.array(), 0, packet.limit() - 40);

    return new ByteBuffer[]{tcpHeader, data};
}
```

Now to get a response from the server, i am using the following code:

```
ByteBuffer responsePacket = ByteBuffer.allocate(65535);
InputStream socketInputStream = socket.getInputStream();
try{
    int responseLength = socketInputStream.read(responsePacket.array());
    if (responseLength > 20){
        Log.e(TAG, "===Server Response===");
        Log.e(TAG, "Length: " + responseLength);

        ByteBuffer trimmedResponseData = ByteBuffer.allocate(responseLength);
        System.arraycopy(responseData.array(), 0, trimmedResponseData.array(), 0, responseLength);

        String resp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < responseLength; i++){
            resp += String.valueOf(responseData.get(i) + " ");
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Response data: " + resp);

        ByteBuffer finalPacket = ByteBuffer.allocate(40 + responseLength);
        ByteBuffer swappedIpHeader = swapSrcDstAddress(getIpHeader(packet)[0]);
        ByteBuffer swappedTcpHeader = swapTCPSrcDst(getTCPHeader(getIpHeader(packet)[1])[0]);

        finalPacket.put(swappedIpHeader.array());
        finalPacket.put(swappedTcpHeader.array());
        finalPacket.put(serverResponseData.array());

        Packet finPack = debugPacket(finalPacket);
        Log.e("VPN", "Final packet --> Packet size: " + finPack.getTotalLength() + " from " + finPack.getSourceIp() + " src port: " + finPack.getSrcPort() + " going to " + finPack.getDestinationIp() + " dst port: " + finPack.getDstPort());

        out.write(finalPacket.array());
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    //Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION: " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code seems to work either EXTREMELY slowly, or not at all. Sometimes if i go to `www.google.com` it will load slowly but most of the time it doesn't. Also some times i am getting the following error on the line `int responseLength = socketInputStream.read(serverResponse.array());`

> java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

What is causing this error, and how can i properly forward these packets to the appropriate destination? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> What is causing this error?

`recvfrom failed` exception means that Server has closed the client socket but client was still reading input data (in your case `serverResponse.array()`. For details, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207394/getting-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-in-android).

> how can i properly forward these packets to the appropriate
>   destination?

There is a sample-code from google-sources [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/ToyVpnService.java) that forwards available packets. Please go through the code and the relevant comments. According to google-sources:

> This application consists of an Android client and a sample
>   implementation of a server. It performs IP over UDP and is capable of
>   doing seamless handover between different networks as long as it
>   receives the same VPN parameters.It shows how to build a VPN client
>   using the VpnService class introduced in API level 14.
>
> The sample code of the server-side implementation is Linux-specific
>   and is available in the `server` directory. To run the server or port
>   it to another platform, please see comments in the code for the
>   details.

one more helpful app link [here](http://www.taosoftware.co.jp/en/android/packetcapture/)

Comment: I have already looked at the toyVpn example from google, but that one uses a separate VPN server. I am trying to implement all of this on the phone itself with no connection to another server.

Comment: the linux-specific server-side implementation is what you have to go through. Go to Server directory as mentioned. Your phone itself is also based on linux.