# Why simple http-server not running in 127.0.0.0:8080 but in 127.0.0.1:8080?

Tags: node.js, httpserver

I need to run a simple http-server using nodejs. I have installed in my local repo using npm. When i run the below command, i am getting th e following message

`nodejs node-modules/http-server/bin/http-server -a 127.0.0.0

 Starting up http-server, serving ./ on: http://127.0.0.0:8080`

But, server is not running on http://127.0.0.0:8080.  All i could see in the screen is, *The webpage is not available*

If i change the command as,

`nodejs node-modules/http-server/bin/http-server -a 127.0.0.1`

it starts a local server at http://127.0.0.1:8080

I do not understand what is going on. Could any body help me to understand what's happening here?

Thanks in ADVANCE!!

Comment: "127.0.0.0 is the network address (with netmask 255.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.0/8).

127.0.0.1 is a host address in that network." From http://superuser.com/questions/575647/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-127-0-0-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`127.0.0.0` is not a valid address.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Addresses_ending_in_0_or_255) article.

Answer (score 0):

First of all take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915188/ip-address-ending-with-zero) question, which tells you why, while an address ending in .0 is perfectly valid, you should avoid using it (hint: legacy reasons).

Then again, node is explicitly telling you where the server is being started, you posted it in your question:

`Starting up http-server, serving ./ on:  ---> http://127.0.0.1:8080 <---`

Even more to the point, 127.0.0.0 is *not* a loopback address, but a generic (potentially assignable) network address. 127.0.0.1, on the other hand, is a loopback address, which means it's assigned to your machine and it's accessible from your machine only. Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) Wikipedia article.

So what can you do? Just run your application on 127.0.0.1, since you can't (and shouldn't probably) run it on 127.0.0.0.